# Date coming up as 12/30/1899 in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my model I have:

```
[DisplayName("Title Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = ("{0:d}"))]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfTitle { get; set; }
```

My View has:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DateOfTitle)</td>
```

The value in the database for this field is null. I would like the `DisplayFor` to show nothing unless there is a valid date for this field. It displays as **12/30/1899**.

Comment: It should display nothing if the value of DateOfTitle is nothing.  You must be setting a value there somewhere in your code.  You can prove this by setting explicitly to null just before you pass it to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this..

```
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", 
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = ("{0:d}"))]
```

Comment: Since the OP wants nothing to show for a null date, `NullDisplayText` could be set to `""`.

Comment: Sure, I was just highlighting the property more than anything, but I've changed it.